# Book object is not iterable: Trying to display similar objects of an instance based on a field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I am working on a library project that displays books and each both is in a category(history, math, adventure, etc). On the detailed view of a book, I want a link (with "See similar books in this category") that will redirect the user to other books of the same category of the current book. So if the detail page of a book has a category of "history", the link will direct to other books in the "history" category. The redirection is to another template (Addon: In helping me out, I would love to display the "similar books" in the same page, not a different page)

**error details**

```
TypeError at /search/similar/bootsrtap/
'Book' object is not iterable
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('index')
    
choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')
choice_list = []
for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)

class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=choice_list)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.author + ": " + self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def similar_book(self):
    return Book.objects.filter(category=self.category)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('detail/<slug:slug>/', BookDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('search/similar/<slug:slug>/', views.search_similar_results, name='search_similar_results'),
```

**views.py**

```
def search_similar_results(request, slug):
    books = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=slug)
    books.similar_book()
    return render(request, 'book/similar_results.html', {'books': books})

class BookDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book'
    template_name = 'book/detail.html'
```

**clickable link to lead to the template**

```
<a href="{% url 'search_similar_results' slug=book.slug %}">Click to see Similar books in this category</a></h3>
            <div class="row">
```

**template**

```
<div class="row">
        {% if books %}
            {% for book in books %}

            <h2>Similar Books in {{ book.category } Category}</h2>
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tm-gallery-item animated bounce infinite">
                <a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">
                <div class="tm-gallery-item-overlay">
                    {% if book.cover %}
                    <img src="{{ book.cover.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid tm-img-center">
                    {% endif %}
                    <p class="small font-italic">Author: {{ book.author }}</p>
                    <p class="small font-italic text-left">Title: {{ book.title }}</p>
                    <p class="small font-italic">Category: {{ book.category }}</p>
                </div>
                </a>
            </figure>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <p>There are No Available Books</p>
        {% endif %}

  </div>
```

**details.html**

```
<div class="tm-main-content no-pad-b">
        
    <!-- Book Detail Page Display -->
    <section class="row tm-item-preview">
        {% if book.cover %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-md-0 mb-5">
            <img src="{{ book.cover.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid tm-img-center-sm card-img-top">
            <h2>Title {{ book.title }}</h2>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <p>No book cover</p>
        {% endif %}
    </section>

    <!-- Similar Books Display by Category -->
    <div class="tm-gallery no-pad-b">
        <h3 style="color: white; text-align: center;"><a href="{% url 'search_similar_results' slug=book.slug %}">Similar books you might be interested in</a></h3>
        <div class="row">
            {% for item in similar_book%}
            <figure class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tm-gallery-item">
                <a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <div class="tm-gallery-item-overlay">
                        <img src="{{ book.cover.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid tm-img-center">
                    </div>
                    <p class="tm-figcaption">Title: {{ book.title}}</p>
                    <p class="tm-figcaption">Category: {{ book.category }}</p>
                </a>
            </figure>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>   
    </div>                               
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the *result* of the similar books to the template, so:

```
def search_similar_results(request, slug):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=slug)
    books = book.similar_book()
    return render(request, 'book/similar_results.html', {'books': books})
```

In the `DetailView`, you can pass the `similar books with:

```
class BookDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book'
    template_name = 'book/detail.html'

    def similar_books(self):
        return self.object.similar_book()
```

Then in the template we work with:

```
{% for item in view.similar_books %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're awesome @Willem Van Onsem. You just relieved me of stress. To my addon, how can I display the "similar results" in the same "detail page". I don't want to redirect to another page. So Users should see similar books on same page

Comment: @samhassan: then you should add the logic to the view where you display the details, and thus pass it through the template of the detailview of the book.

Comment: How will I then restructure the url to point back to the detail page. It gives this error: NoReverseMatch at /search/similar/bootsrtap/
Reverse for 'search_similar_results' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/similar/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: @samhassan: that is because the slug is empty, or you use a variable for the slug that does not exists.

Comment: I do appreciate your time a lot. I am relatively new to Django. Can you please refactor the code for me. This is my first StackOverflow question

Comment: @samhassan: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67752746/edit) the question with the detail view.

Comment: @samhassan: that is *not* the view, but the template.

Comment: I've taken out the Link to redirect to another page. It's now just a heading. The results for the search_similar_results is now stored in "similar_books" as seen from the detail.html

Comment: @samhassan: but the *template* is not that interesting, it is the view that needs to provide the data to the template, so the *view* should have code to retrieve similar books.

Comment: How can I refactor the url.py? Because the 'search_similar_results' seem not to be needed.

Comment: @samhassan: you can remove that url, view, and template. Since the detail view simply will show the similar books. So a link to a special page is not neccesary.

Comment: It works!!! You're really a Gem and a good teacher. I'm barely 3 months into learning Django

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do appreciate your time and patience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233058/discussion-between-sam-hassan-and-willem-van-onsem).